# How can correlate against multiple columns using ddply?

Tags: r, plyr, correlation

I have a data.frame and I want to calculate correlation coefficients using one column against the other columns (there are some non-numeric columns in the frame as well).

```
ddply(Banks,.(brand_id,standard.quarter),function(x) { cor(BLY11,x) })
# Error in cor(BLY11, x) : 'y' must be numeric
```

I tested against is.numeric(x)

```
ddply(Banks,.(brand_id,standard.quarter),function(x) { if is.numeric(x) cor(BLY11,x) else 0 })
```

but that failed every comparison and returned 0 and returned only one column, as if its only being called once.  What is being passed to the function?  Just coming to R and I think there's something fundamental I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this one

```
cor(longley[, 1], longley[ , sapply(longley, is.numeric)])



    GNP.deflator       GNP Unemployed Armed.Forces Population      Year  Employed
[1,]            1 0.9915892  0.6206334    0.4647442  0.9791634 0.9911492 0.9708985
```

Comment: Basically the same as my answer, with `sed s/d/longley/ <mine >yours` ;) -- except I see now that there's not need for my explicitly conversion to a matrix. Thanks.

Comment: Great!  So close, ddply(Banks,.(brand_id,standard.quarter),function(x) {cor(x$BLY11, x[ , sapply(x, is.numeric)])}) - gets me the correlations, but I've lost the column names.  They are all V1 ... V167.  How best to get the original column names to come along?

Comment: @LCricket wrap the `cor(...)` in `as.data.frame()` to force your function to return a data.frame rather than letting `plyr` coerce it to one.

Answer (score 5):

From ?cor:

> If ‘x’ and ‘y’ are matrices then the covariances (or correlations)
>   between the columns of ‘x’ and the columns of ‘y’ are computed.

So your only real job is to remove the non-numeric columns:

```
# An example data.frame containing a non-numeric column
d <- cbind(fac=c("A","B"), mtcars)

## Calculate correlations between the mpg column and all numeric columns
cor(d$mpg, as.matrix(d[sapply(d, is.numeric)]))
     mpg       cyl       disp         hp      drat         wt     qsec
[1,]   1 -0.852162 -0.8475514 -0.7761684 0.6811719 -0.8676594 0.418684
            vs        am      gear       carb
[1,] 0.6640389 0.5998324 0.4802848 -0.5509251
```

**Edit:** And in fact, as @MYaseen208's answer shows, there's no need to explicitly convert data.frames to matrices. Both of the following work just fine:

```
cor(d$mpg, d[sapply(d, is.numeric)])

cor(mtcars, mtcars)
```

Answer (score 2):

ddply splits a data.frame into chunks and sends them (smaller data.frames) to your function.  your `x` is a data.frame with the same columns as `Banks`.  Thus, `is.numeric(x)` is `FALSE`.  `is.data.frame(x)` should return `TRUE`.

try:

```
function(x) { 
  cor(x$BLY11, x$othercolumnname) 
}
```

Comment: This will work for a specific column, but what if I want it to go against every other columns?  There are over 100 of them.

Comment: you can write them out or use something like `lapply(columnnames, function(n) cor(x$BLY11, x[n]))` where `columnnames` is a vector of your column names you want to compare.

Answer (score 2):

This function operates on a chunk:

```
calc_cor_only_numeric = function(chunk) {
   is_numeric = sapply(chunk, is.numeric)
   return(cor(chunk[-is_numeric]))
 }
```

And can be used by `ddply`:

```
ddply(banks, .(cat1, cat2), calc_cor_only_numeric)
```

I could not check the code, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're doing can be done with `sapply` as well:

```
with(Banks,
  sapply( list(brand_id,standard.quarter), function(x) cor(BLY11,x) )
)
```

Comment: Just tried this, and received the same error:
Error in cor(BLY11, x) : 'y' must be numeric

Comment: Are your columns numeric? Check with `is.numeric(Banks$brand_id)` and similar. Or more generically, `sapply(names(Banks), function(x) class(Banks[,x,drop=TRUE]))`